# Visualizer broken on Samsung Galaxy S4?

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

On my Nexus 7 (with Android 4.3), my Visualizer code will work fine: onFftDataCapture() returns an array full of data. Also, onWaveFormDataCapture() returns a byte array full of data.

HOWEVER - on my Galaxy S4 (with Android 4.3) my Visualizer code does *not* work fine: onFftDataCapture() returns a byte array full of 0's. Also, onWaveFormDataCapture() returns a byte array full of -128's

Is this a confirmed known issue?
Is there a work-around ?

The closest snip of information that I've been able to uncover is... but nothing is confirmed by Samsung
 http://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=GeneralB&messageId=238327&frm=7&tagValue=S4&curPage=1

Comment: also, same code works on Samsung Tab 3 once the media volume is taken off mute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After hours of searching I've discovered that, yes, the Samsung Galaxy S4 and other devices are F'd up.

Source: https://github.com/felixpalmer/android-visualizer/issues/5#issuecomment-25900391